# check name already exist in modules in forms using ajax in odoo

Tags: javascript, ajax, odoo

I have created a form from where I fetch informations to the custom modules. I want to show error using js if the value I am posting in the form is equal to the name in the name in the custom module.
 I know we can use ajax but how?
Thanks in advance 
Lets see who can solve my problem